# private final int offset in java.lang.String implementation

Tags: java

In String class implementation ([here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)) I found this declaration:

```
/** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
private final int offset;
```

So what is this value for? Why not to save all strings starting with the first position?

Comment: While I haven't seen the code, my guess would be that they use it for substrings.  That way you can avoid having to re-allocate and share the underlying character array.

Comment: [This no longer exists in current versions of Java.](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/)